# Align checkbox to center

Tags: css, vuetify.js

I am using v-data-table. I am trying to align the checkbox to center because it is automatically aligned left when using the data table even if I used `align: center` on it. Here is the object on my data table header:
`{ text: this.$t('Actions'), value: 'actions', width:'10%', align:'center', sortable: false , divider: true},`

On my v-data-table tag, I used on `<template>` tag as follows:

```
<template v-slot:item.visibility="{ item }">
    <v-checkbox
      v-model="item.isVisible">
    </v-checkbox>
</template>
```

I tried using the `<center>` tag, `align-items: center` on CSS when I assigned a class on it, using the `class="text-center"` and  `class="justify-center"`. But none of them worked. Is there any way to manipulate the alignment of data in v-data-table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use class `d-flex justify-center`.

`justify-center` works only when the display is flex. so set it using `d-flex`

Comment: yes, i tried adding the `d-flex` and it worked. thank you.

Comment: @bliss please approve this answer if this is working. The one you approved is copy of mine and this is the first posted answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try below:

```
<template>
  <v-container class="d-flex justify-center" fluid >

    <v-checkbox
      v-model="item.isVisible">
    </v-checkbox>

  </v-container>
</template>
```

Comment: This is the exact copy of my answer. Doesnot have anything other than I stated.